# ZF3 - using partial from outside of module directory

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I'm building ZF3 based application with my own library that contains base components to include in other projects. Library is composer based so the application tree looks like this:

```
- module
-- Application
--- src
---- view
----- index.phtml (where I want to include partial from base)
- vendor
-- myBaseScripts (installed via composer)
--- partials
---- myTablePartial.phtml (partial to include)
```

Can I include partial that is not inside of **module/Application/view** but inside **vendor/myBaseScripts/partials**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. However, you're hereby advised to make sure that the module you're creating contains a default view.

---

To register a view partial, use the config of a module, like so:

```
'view_manager' => [
    'template_map' => [
        'name/of/partial/view' => __DIR__ . '/../path/relative/to/config/file/view-partial.phtml',
    ],
],
```

Make sure that your module contains something like the above.

You then use this in a view like so:

```
<?= $this->partial('name/of/partial/view', ['param1' => 'value1']) ?>
```

`$this->partial` is a [ViewHelper](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html). The first argument it takes is which partial to load (by name!). The second parameter is an optional array, which contains key/value pairs for data.

---

To overwrite a partial, such as a default module partial, with a custom one in another module, you must overwrite the value of the key/value pair in the config.

This module, with the modified partial, *must be loaded **after** the 'original' one*. This is to ensure that the config gets overwritten in the order you're expecting.

Assuming the code above is in your original module, you would do the below in another module:

```
'view_manager' => [
    'template_map' => [
        'name/of/partial/view' => __DIR__ . '/../path/relative/to/config/file/this-is-a-custom-partial.phtml',
    ],
],
```

As you can see, the name is still the same.

Happy coding.